# Нехорошо разлогинивать во время написания вопроса

Tags: дефект, нытьё

После завершения техподдержки сайта решил задать [вопрос о локализации заголовка страницы](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9517/178988). На момент открытия страницы я был залогинен. Но когда я всё написал, оказалось, что я уже не залогинен, соответственно вопрос не отправлялся. Показывались две ошибки про 5 баллов репутации и про вход на сайт.

Ну как-то это не круто, когда разлогиниваешься во время написания вопроса. Уж тогда бы во время техподдержки все сессии дропали.

[image: скриншот]