# Во время вопроса произошла ошибка

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, вопросы

Что за странное сообщение такое?

> Во время вопроса произошла ошибка.

Воспроизводится так:

- Начать задавать вопрос
- [Словить автоматическое разлогирование](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9518/178988)
- Залогиниться в соседней вкладке
- Попробовать отправить вопрос

> [image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Текст сообщения](https://ru.traducir.win/string/3060) исправлен на:

> Во время публикации вопроса произошла ошибка.