# Странно сохраняются данные из неотправленного вопроса

Tags: дефект, вопросы

Пока задавал вопрос, [меня разлогинили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9518/178988), я залогинился, но даже после этого [не смог его задать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9519/178988). Тогда я то ли открыл открыл ссылку [Задать вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) в новой вкладке, то ли продублировал текущую вкладку (не уверен) и там я увидел результат автосохранения вопроса (слева - оригинальный текст, справа - восстановленный):

> [image: скриншот вопросов]

Причём, я точно помнб последовательнсоть действий при написании вопроса:

- Написать заголовок `We are Offline`
- Начать писать тело вопроса
- Изменить заголовок на `Перевести We are Offline`
- Дописать тело вопроса
- Загрузить скриншот
- Поставить метки

Однако видно, что тело сохранено полностью, метки тоже, а вот заголовок куда-то пропал, хотя он точно был написан раньше, да в других случаях заголовок сохраняется. Как так получилось?

Кстати, на этот раз (после копипаста заголовка) вопрос мне тоже не удалось отправить, так же,как и из прошлой вкладки:

> [image: скриншот отправки]

После этого я открыл в новой вкладе главную страницу и перешёл с неё по ссылке [Задать вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), и попробовал отправить (не помню, пришлось заново копипастить заголовок или нет). Получил капчу, успешно прошёл её и вопрос наконец-то отправился.

Но и тут потом обнаружился сюрприз:

> [image: скриншот вопроса]

Вместо метки [локализации](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8) написано только [лока](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0) - та часть метки, которую я ввёл до выбора метки из списка. Можно было бы подумать, что метка не успела сохраниться при разлогинивании, но нет, на правой части скриншота с двумя окнами видно, что первый раз было восстановлено полное написание метки.

Comment: "Во время вопроса произошла ошибка" // довольно странно звучит (уже поправил перевод). Но, если всё же какая-то ошибка имела место быть, то несколько странно удивляться странностям при восстановлении из бэкапа.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, насколько я понял по капче, ошибка была в том, что SO меня за робота принял, а на капчу чего-то не хватило.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, если поменял, отпишись в [соответствующем вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9519/178988).